# Public GraphQL directives

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, graphql-playground

This is my Schema.

```
Query {
    me: User @isAuthenticated
}
```

When I add `@isAuthenticated` it is handled on server side but in `GraphQL Playground` the directive doesn't show. I have some role based access system and I want to show all the role directives publicly so that API user can understand what role is wanted for which query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema directives can be used to transform the schema or add functionality to it, but they cannot be used to expose any sort of metadata to the client. There's ongoing discussion [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/300) with regards to how to implement that sort of functionality. For the time being, your best bet would be to utilize descriptions.

```
"""
**Required roles**: `ADMIN` 
"""
Query {
  me: User @isAuthenticated
}
```

Comment: Ohh that seems very intense discussion. I was using description but it seems like duplication. I guess we will have to wait for spec to finish.